# C++ array of wheel on the heap deep copy

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, deep-copy

Here is my code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Wheel
{
public:
        Wheel()
    {
        pressure = 32;
        ptrSize = new int(30);
    }
    Wheel(int s, int p)
    {
        ptrSize = new int(s);
        pressure = p;
    }
    ~Wheel()
    {
        delete ptrSize;
    }
    void pump(int amount)
    {
       pressure += amount;
    }

private:
    int *ptrSize;
    int pressure;
};

class RacingCar
{
public:
    RacingCar()
    {
        speed = 0;
        Wheel carWheels = new Wheel[3];
    }
    RacingCar(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }
    void Accelerate()
    {
        speed = speed + 10;
    }

private:
    int speed;
};
```

I using this code to create a RacingCar object:

```
RacingCar test();
```

Yet am getting the following error:

> [BCC32 Error] Question 4.cpp(48): E2285 Could not find a match for 'Wheel::Wheel(const Wheel&)'

At line:

```
Wheel carWheels = new Wheel[3];
```

I am wanting to create an array of 4 wheels as an array of objects on the heap.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am wanting to use a copy constructor for class RacingCar that will create a deep copies of RacingCar objects and then write code to prove that the copy of the RacingCar object is a deep copy.

Can I please have some help to do this?

Here is my code:

```
class RacingCar
{
public:
    RacingCar()
    {
        speed = 0;
        Wheel* carWheels = new Wheel[3];
    }
    RacingCar(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }
    RacingCar(const RacingCar &oldObject)
    {
        //I am not sure what to place here.
        Wheel* carWheels = new Wheel[3];

    }
    void Accelerate()
    {
        speed = speed + 10;
    }

private:
    int speed;
};
```

*** 2nd UPDATE**

Here is my current code:

```
class Wheel
{
public:
    Wheel() : pressure(32)
    {
        ptrSize = new int(30);
    }
    Wheel(int s, int p) : pressure(p)
    {
        ptrSize = new int(s);
    }
    ~Wheel()
    {
        delete ptrSize;
    }
    void pump(int amount)
    {
        pressure += amount;
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return *ptrSize;
    }
    int getPressure()
    {
        return pressure;
    }
private:
    int *ptrSize;
    int pressure;
};

class RacingCar
{
public:
    RacingCar()
    {
        speed = 0;
        *carWheels = new Wheel[4];
    }
    RacingCar(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }
    RacingCar(const RacingCar &oldObject)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(carWheels)/sizeof(carWheels[0]); ++i)
        {
            Wheel oldObjectWheel = oldObject.getWheel(i);
            carWheels[i]=new Wheel(oldObjectWheel.getSize(),oldObjectWheel.getPressure());
        }

    }
    void Accelerate()
    {
        speed = speed + 10;
    }
    Wheel getWheel(int id)
    {
        return *carWheels[id];
    }
private:
    int speed;
    Wheel *carWheels[4];
};
```

The copy constructor is not working correctly. I am getting an error at:

```
Wheel oldObjectWheel = oldObject.getWheel(i);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also you probably want `Wheel[4]` - most cars don't have only 3 :)

Comment: if you want to prove deep copy in `RacingCar` I think you should change `Wheel`'s `ptrSize` from a pointer to a value. And write the `ctor` and `operator=` in `RacingCar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an example of deep-copy, wish this helps.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Demo
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Demo()
    {
        ptrNeedsDeepCopy = new int(10);
    }

    // Copy constructor
    Demo(const Demo& rhs)
    {
        // You need to allocate new memory to make sure the two
        // objects are not pointing to the same memeory.
        ptrNeedsDeepCopy = new int(*(rhs.ptrNeedsDeepCopy));
    }

    // Copy assign operator
    Demo& operator=(const Demo& rhs)
    {
        // Do things same in the copy constructor
        // AND!!! you have to check that the object is not
        // assigning it to itself.
        if(this != &rhs)
        {
            ptrNeedsDeepCopy = new int(*(rhs.ptrNeedsDeepCopy));  
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Demo()
    {
        delete ptrNeedsDeepCopy;
    }

    void SomeMemberFunctions()
    {
        // What ever.
    }

    int GetPtrValue()
    {
        if(ptrNeedsDeepCopy)
        {
            return *ptrNeedsDeepCopy;
        }
    }

    void SetPtrValue(int val)
    {
        if(ptrNeedsDeepCopy)
        {
            *ptrNeedsDeepCopy = val;  
        }
    }

private:
    int *ptrNeedsDeepCopy;

};

int main()
{
    Demo a;
    Demo b = a;

    cout << "a's initial value: " << a.GetPtrValue() << endl;
    cout << "b's initial value: " << b.GetPtrValue() << endl;


    a.SetPtrValue(7);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "a's changed value: " << a.GetPtrValue() << endl;
    cout << "b's changed value: " << b.GetPtrValue() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have made a 2nd Update to my code. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek You got the error because in your `RacingCar`'s copy constructor, `oldObject.getWheel(i);` is not a const function, and is called by a `const RacingCar&`. Change `Wheel getWheel(int id)` to `Wheel getWheel(int id) const` will fix this compile error, but I think you are not understanding deep copy here. I think you don't need to maintain a pointer in the `Wheel` class, all you need to deep copy is the `Wheel*`'s in your `RacingCar` class, please read http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Answer (score 3):

That's a syntax error, it should be

```
 Wheel* carWheels = new Wheel[3];
```

`new` returns a pointer type - a pointer to the very first `Wheel` in the array, so `carWheels[i]` works as intended to access the `i`th wheel.

**Consider allocating four (4) wheels unless you're sure your car is ok with three (3).**

Comment: Doesn't Wheel* carWheels = new Wheel[3] have 4 items in the array? 0,1,2,3?

Comment: No, big warning on that. The indexing is zero-based, but not the numbers themselves. `new Wheel[4]` creates four `Wheel` instances, accessible by indices 0,1,2,3. `new Wheel[0]` creates an empty array.

Comment: Hint: follow the rule of three for `Wheel`, then do a plain element-wise copy (i.e. `new_arr[0] = old_arr[0]; ..`). Proof their independence by verifying that their `ptrSize` members have different addresses.

Comment: What is a 'plain element-wise copy'?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a `Wheel` called `carWheels` and initialize its value to a pointer to an array of 3 `Wheel`s. You probably want:

```
Wheel* carWheels = new Wheel[3];
```